# How to get a value from HTML into PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to store a user input into PHP variable but I not able to do so. Here is the code that fetches values from database:

```
<?php
    while($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Query_Result)) {
    { 
?>                               
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $Row['Product_Name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Row['Product_Type'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Row['Product_Price'] ?></td>

            //the "qty" box does not exist in the database. I want user to enter a number in "qty" box and that number should be stored in a php variable 

            <td><input id="qty" type="number" name="qty" ></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $Row['Product_ID'] ?>)"</td>
        </tr>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Here is the Javascript for addtocart() function:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function addtocart(pid) {
        document.form1.Product_ID.value=pid;
        document.form1.command.value='add';
        document.form1.submit();
    }
</script>

<?php
    require 'ConnectDB.php';
    require 'functions.php';

    if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='add' &&   $_REQUEST['Product_ID']>0 ) {
        $pid=$_REQUEST['Prodcut_ID'];
        // This addtocart() function here sets the qauntity to 1 by default.. I want it to be dynamic. User should input the qauntity and I should be able to pass it to the addtocart()        function

        addtocart($pid,1);
        header("location:shopping.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Please help!

Comment: And you won't be able to do so, as by the time the user inputs something, the code that makes up the page has long since been sent from the server, and the only way to get data back to the server is to reload the page or manually send the data back with something like ajax.

Comment: Take a look at [Handling Forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is not well formatted, so I have edited for you:

```
<?php while( $Row = mysql_fetch_array( $Query_Result ) ): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $Row['Product_Name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Row['Product_Type'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Row['Product_Price'] ?></td>

        <!-- the "qty" box does not exist in the database. I want user to enter a  number      in     "qty" box and that number should be stored in a php variable -->

        <td><input id="qty" type="number" name="qty" ></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo $Row['Product_ID'] ?>)"</td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

What you need to do is add an input field as you have, and put the row id into it something like this (I am presuming your row id is `id`...

```
<input id="qty" type="number" name="qty[<?php echo $Row['id'] ?>]" >
```

Then you can use a PHP POST or JavaScript AJAX action on this, to submit this and have it stored, this is a separate aspect that you need to decide before people can help...

Comment: I tried using PHP POST method but get an error "Undefined index 'qty' " Could you please help me with the POST method?

Comment: could you please help?

Comment: @Kaps I can't really help because you've not shared any code that means I could have a clue what is going on, and the question isn't very clear.